# Messed up my code terribly with throwing/catching exceptions and try...catch blocks

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Alright, I know I messed up bad with catching and throwing exceptions, but I can't figure them out for the life of me. I think I'm mixing several different ways to do them. Can anyone guide me in the right direction (not looking for complete answer, just what the code is supposed to resemble)? It gets stuck on the "throw new ();" lines, and the catch blocks. Everything else seems to not have any issues. It's supposed to be an improvement on a previous project, http://pastebin.com/sjR0BZBY. you can run this if you'd like to see what the program is supposed to do if that helps.

```
public class Project6 extends JFrame
 {
 // Declaring variables
 private JLabel enterLabel, resultsLabel, errorLabel;
 private JTextField queryField, errorField;
 private JButton goB, clearB;
 private JTextArea textArea;
 private Container c;
 private JPanel panel;

 // main method
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Project6 p6 = new Project6();
   p6.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   p6.setSize(new Dimension(455, 550));
   p6.setVisible(true);
 }

 // creating JFrame
 public Project6()
 {
   c = getContentPane();

   c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

   setTitle("");
   c.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

   ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

   enterLabel = new JLabel("Enter query here:");
   c.add(enterLabel); 

   queryField = new JTextField(35);
   c.add(queryField);

   goB = new JButton("GO!");
   c.add(goB);
   goB.addActionListener(handler);

   resultsLabel = new JLabel("Results:");
   c.add(resultsLabel);

   textArea = new JTextArea(20, 30);
   c.add(textArea);

   errorLabel = new JLabel("-------------Error messages:");
   c.add(errorLabel);

   errorField = new JTextField(35);
   c.add(errorField);

   clearB = new JButton("Clear");
   c.add(clearB);
   clearB.addActionListener(handler);
 }

 // ActionListener for buttons
 private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    // Go! button
    if (e.getSource() == goB){

         String str = queryField.getText();
         StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(str, ", ");
         int numToks = tokens.countTokens();
         String[] tokenArray = new String[numToks];         
         int i = 0;

         // creating all tokenizing, validations, and the works. Try and bear    with it, it works but it's a rough trip
         while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()){

         // while loop to create tokens
         while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
         str = tokens.nextToken();         
         tokenArray[i] = str;         
         System.out.println(tokenArray[i]);
         i++;  }
         // start if verifications, everything else
         String query = tokenArray[3];
         String optok = tokenArray[4];
         String index = tokenArray[5];
         String qField = queryField.getText();
          try {
               if (qField.equals(""))
                  throw new MissingInputException();
               else {
               if (numToks != 6)
                  throw new IncorrectFormatException();
               else {               
               if (tokenArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Report"))
                {
                  if (tokenArray[1].equalsIgnoreCase("all"))
                   {
                     if (tokenArray[2].equals("where"))
                       {
                        if (tokenArray[3].equals("basePrice") || tokenArray[3].equals("quality") || tokenArray[3].equals("numInStock"))
                         {
                         if (tokenArray[4].equals("<") || tokenArray[4].equals(">") || tokenArray[4].equals(">=")||tokenArray[4].equals("<=")||tokenArray[4].equals("=="))
                          {
                           if (query.equals("basePrice"))
                             { BasePriceM(query, index, optok); }
                           else if (query.equals("quality"))
                            {  QualityM(query, index, optok); }
                           else if (query.equals("numInStock"))
                             { NumInStockM(query, index, optok); }
                           }
                          else
                          throw new InvalidOperatorException();
                         }
                        else
                         throw new InvalidLValueException();
                        }
                       else
                        throw new InvalidQualifierException();
                       }
                      else
                        throw new InvalidSelectorException();
                       }
                      else
                        throw new IllegalStartOfQueryException();
                       }
                      }


            } // end try
            catch(MissingInputException aa)
            {
               errorField.setText("Enter an expression");  
               queryField.setText("");
            }
            catch(IncorrectFormatException ab)
            {
               errorField.setText("Error, field too large or small");
               queryField.setText("");            
            }
            catch(IllegalStartOfQueryException ac)
            {
            errorField.setText("Error, report expected");  
            queryField.setText("");            
            }
            catch(InvalidSelectorException ad)
            {
               errorField.setText("Error, all expected");
               queryField.setText("");            
            }
            catch(InvalidQualifierException ae)
            {
                errorField.setText("Error, where expected");
                queryField.setText("");
            }
            catch(InvalidLValueException af)
            {
               errorField.setText("Error, basePrice, Quality, numInStock expected");
               queryField.setText("");           
            }
            catch(InvalidOperatorException ag)
            {
               errorField.setText("Error, < > >= <= == expected");
               queryField.setText("");            
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException af)
            {

            }                

        }// end of while loop
     } // end go button

      // clear all button
    if (e.getSource() == clearB)
      {
        queryField.setText("");
        textArea.setText("");
        errorField.setText("");   
      }
   }
  } // end buttons
  // methods for printing

 public void BasePriceM(String query, String index, String optok)
 {
 int pos = 0;
 int index1 = index.indexOf(".", pos);
 if (index1 > -1)
  {
   double b = Double.parseDouble(index);
     if (b > 0.05 && b < 5400.0)
       {printBasePrice(query, optok, b);}
      else{
        errorField.setText("Invalid query, must be between 0.05 and 5400.0");
        queryField.setText(""); }}
 }

 public void QualityM(String query, String index, String optok)
 {
 int pos2 = 0;
                      int index2 = index.indexOf(".", pos2);
                       if (index2 == -1)
                       {                         
                         int n = Integer.parseInt(index);
                         if (n > 0)
                           {                              
                             printBasePrice(query, optok, n);                              
                           }
                        else{
                        errorField.setText("Invalid query, must be greater than 0");
                        queryField.setText(""); }}
 }

 public void NumInStock(String query, String index, String optok)
 {
 int pos2 = 0;
                      int index2 = index.indexOf(".", pos2);
                       if (index2 == -1)
                       {                         
                         int n = Integer.parseInt(index);
                         if (n > 0)
                           {                              
                             printBasePrice(query, optok, n);                              
                           }
                        else{
                        errorField.setText("Invalid query, must be greater than 0");
                        queryField.setText("");} }
 }
 public void printQuality(String query, String optok, int p)
 {
   textArea.append("Search for " + query +" "+ optok +" "+ p + "\n");
 }
 public void printBasePrice(String query, String optok, double b)
 {
   textArea.append("Search for " + query +" "+ optok +" "+ b + "\n");
 }
 public void printNumInStock(String query, String optok, int n)
 {
   textArea.append("Search for " + query +" "+ optok +" "+ n + "\n");
 }
} // end program`enter code here`
```

Comment: You may want to explain where your exceptions/which exception types are causing issues, it's unlikely most people will read all of this.

Comment: `MissingInputException`, `IncorrectFormatException`, `InvalidOperatorException`, `InvalidLValueException`, `InvalidQualifierException`, `InvalidSelectorException`, `IllegalStartOfQueryException` are undefined (unknown classes)

Comment: All 7 exceptions throws, and then the 7 catch blocks are producing errors. I know I did something completely wrong when writing the code but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You want to search for "clean code" by Robert Martin and study how to not write messy code. Basically it is a bad idea to add code; while your code is not compiling. Do the opposite: always just write a few lines; then run the compiler. Do not write more code, until you fixed all the compiler errors. Anything else is just asking for trouble (and wasting everybody's energy).